# Wordpress conditional redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress website, where I am trying to redirect users to a different page based on a URL parameter. This is what I am trying to solve:-

> Current page: - www.mysite.com/hi/

If there is a parameter 'report=show', then I would want the user to be directly redirected to a different page:-

> **www.mysite.com/hi/?report=show** should redirect the user to
>   **www.mysite.com/report** If the parameter does not exist, the user should be shown *www.mysite.com/hi/*

I tried doing a htacess rewrite, but it didn't make any difference.. don't know why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the .htaccess isn't working (as you didn't post it).

Easiest way though is to use the Wordpress [Redirection Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).

You would add a new redirect rule.  Keep the defaults for the other settings, and enter the following two values:

- Source URL: /hi/?report=shows
- Target Url: /report

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip @manishie . The plugin really did the job!